# How to merge split data with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge, sql-server-2012

**Original answer:**
I needed to split strings by specified delimiter. I have achieved this with guide on [SQL Performance - T-SQL Queries - Split Strings](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) using `Numbers Table`. However, once the string is split, how to merge it back into the columns? So the result of split string in this form:

```
**Item**
a
id
xyz
abcd
a
id
xyz
abcd
```

Transforms to this form:

```
C1 C2  C3   C4
a  id  xyz  abc
a  id  xyz  abc
```

and so on?

---

**Update based on Goat`s answer**:

```
/abc/def/ghi/jkl.html_abc_def
```

should be split into

```
C1   C2   C3   C4   C5
abc  def  ghi  jkl  html_abc_def
```

This is what I have so far

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT testString = 'abc/def/ghi/jkl.html_abc_def'
            ),
     splitString
     AS (SELECT *,
         CONVERT(XML, '<String><Section>'
                      + Replace(Replace((substring(teststring,1,patindex('%.html%',teststring)-1)),'_','/'), '/', '</Section><Section>')
                      + '</Section></String>') AS xmlString
         FROM   CTE)
SELECT xmlstring.value('/String[1]/Section[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS Col1,
       xmlstring.value('/String[1]/Section[2]', 'varchar(100)') AS Col2,
       xmlstring.value('/String[1]/Section[3]', 'varchar(100)') AS Col3,
       xmlstring.value('/String[1]/Section[4]', 'varchar(100)') AS Col4,
       xmlstring.value('/String[1]/Section[5]', 'varchar(100)') AS Col5,
       xmlstring.value('/String[1]/Section[6]', 'varchar(100)') AS Col6
FROM   splitstring;

--select substring(teststring,1,patindex('%.html%',teststring)-1) first
--substring(teststring,patindex('%.html%',teststring)+1,200) second
```

The first substring gets the data to `.html` and the second gets the data behind it. But I dont know how to put it all together.

**Got it:**

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT testString = 'abc/def/ghi/jkl.html_abc_def'
            ),
     splitString
     AS (SELECT *,
         CONVERT(XML, '<String><Section>'
                      + Replace(Replace((substring(teststring,1,patindex('%.html%',teststring)-1)),'_','/'), '/', '</Section><Section>')
                      + '</Section></String>'
                      + '<String><Section>'
                      + substring(teststring,patindex('%.html%',teststring)+1,200)
                      + '</Section></String>'
                      ) AS xmlString
         FROM   CTE)
SELECT xmlstring.value('/String[1]/Section[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS Col1,
       xmlstring.value('/String[1]/Section[2]', 'varchar(100)') AS Col2,
       xmlstring.value('/String[1]/Section[3]', 'varchar(100)') AS Col3,
       xmlstring.value('/String[1]/Section[4]', 'varchar(100)') AS Col4,
       xmlstring.value('/String[2]/Section[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS Col5
FROM   splitstring;
```

Comment: You want to split a string to columns, instead of rows, right?

Comment: Yes. What I did first was the guide on the link. However it returns all split data into one single column, not multiple ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than splitting to rows first, you can split a delimited string to individual columns using `XML` functionality:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT testString = 'test,1,2,3'
              UNION  SELECT 'test,2,3,4'
              UNION  SELECT 'test,5,6,7')
     ,SplitString AS (SELECT *,
                             CONVERT(XML,'<String><Section>'+ REPLACE(testString,',', '</Section><Section>') + '</Section></String>') AS xmlString
                      FROM cte
                      )    
 SELECT xmlString.value('/String[1]/Section[1]','varchar(100)') AS Col1
       ,xmlString.value('/String[1]/Section[2]','varchar(100)') AS Col2
       ,xmlString.value('/String[1]/Section[3]','varchar(100)') AS Col3
       ,xmlString.value('/String[1]/Section[4]','varchar(100)') AS Col4
 FROM SplitString
```

Note: The above uses a comma as the delimiter, alter the `REPLACE()` accordingly.

**Update**:  Glad you got it sorted, it looks like you might be over-complicating the XML creation though, I think you could just replace `.` with `/` then use `/` in the 2nd `REPLACE()`:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT testString = 'abc/def/ghi/jkl.html_abc_def')
     ,SplitString AS (SELECT *,
                             CONVERT(XML,'<String><Section>'+ REPLACE(REPLACE(testString,'.','/'),'/', '</Section><Section>') + '</Section></String>') AS xmlString
                      FROM cte
                      )    
 SELECT xmlString.value('/String[1]/Section[1]','varchar(100)') AS Col1
       ,xmlString.value('/String[1]/Section[2]','varchar(100)') AS Col2
       ,xmlString.value('/String[1]/Section[3]','varchar(100)') AS Col3
       ,xmlString.value('/String[1]/Section[4]','varchar(100)') AS Col4
       ,xmlString.value('/String[1]/Section[5]','varchar(100)') AS Col5
 FROM SplitString
```

Comment: What if there are two kind of delimiters? E.g. one is "/", the second is "-". Can this also be built into this solution?

Comment: @DNac Certainly, you could either do the split in 2 steps, first on one delimiter then the other, or you could add another `REPLACE()` to make all the delimiters the same:
`CONVERT(XML,'<String><Section>'+ REPLACE(REPLACE(testString,'/','-'),'-', '</Section><Section>') + '</Section></String>') AS xmlString`

Comment: OK, this is great. Thank you. Last question: Could you please help me how to achieve this? I have e.g. string /abc/def/ghi/jkl.html_abc_def. How to put part since .html into one column and not to split them anymore? Ill update the answer for better understanding.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for help! I am really happy for this solution :)

Comment: @DNac Nice, just noticed your follow-up question, might be able to simplify your `XML` creation, see update.

Comment: The thing is the string is also  /ab_c/d_ef/ghi/jkl.html_abc_def sometimes. I did not mentioned this due simplify the question. I assume in that case it needs to be done as in my update.